# Angular Material md-contact-chips autocomplete issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I have a problem using the `md-contact-chips` autocompletion. I try to catch the `$query` as soon as anybody starts typing something.

**HTML**

```html
<md-contact-chips
   ng-model="members"
   md-contacts="querySearch($query)"
   md-contact-name="fullname"
   md-contact-email="email"
   md-contact-image="image"
   filter-selected="true"
   md-require-match
   placeholder="Add members">
</md-contact-chips>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.querySearch = function($query) {
    console.log($query);
};
```

When I try to search for additional members (which all are in my `$scope.members`) I get this JS error.

```
TypeError: $scope.textChange is not a function
```

I'm using Angular 1.4.1 and Material 0.10.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use the workaround suggested [on this page](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3388) by **norkunas**.

Add `md-selected-item-change="null" md-search-text-change="null"` to the md-contact-chips element.

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, can you mark this as solved.
Note that a new version of Angular Material 1.x.x is now out and this should no longer be needed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and couldn't figure out why.
I downgraded my angularjs version to 1.3.15, which is what material.angularjs.org is using. And it works fine.